# Apache Rewrite url for get request

Tags: regex, apache, url, url-rewriting

I want that if a user type

> http://myhost.com/countryname/my-page-1

should call my file

> http://myhost.com/mypage1.php?country=countryname

How can i do such redirect in apache ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.+?)-(\d+)/?$ $2$3.php?country=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments below you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\s]+)/facebook-followers-likes$ facebooklikesfollowerscountry.php?country=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It didn't worked. I have copied this in my .htaccess file. But it didn't worked is there any other info that i can give to you ? So that you can make it work.

Comment: Ok I need answers of all of these questions. Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is full path of above .htaccess?

Comment: after searching a lot my task is done using this
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/facebook-followers-likes$ facebooklikesfollowerscountry.php?country=$1 [L]`

but the countries which have white space in their name are still not working. What is needed to updated in my RegEx ?

Comment: To match spaces use: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-\s]+)/facebook-followers-likes$ facebooklikesfollowerscountry.php?country=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: I have updated the answer with this rule, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.